# Issue with dropdown in navbar - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Do you guys know why my dropdown in navbar is like this? I'm using the bootstrap framework for my css.

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu1he.png)

The css for the dropdown is as followed:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem; }
```

Here is the html for the header:

```html
<header>
    <div class="container" style="height: 80px;">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" style="max-width: 130px;" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Hem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projekt <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <!--<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ungdomligt Engagemang</a>-->
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="om-oss.php">Om oss</a></li>
                <li><a href="medlem.php">Bli medlem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="socmeddropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sociala Medier <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="socmeddropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.instagram.com/samhallets.unga/" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://discord.gg/pkJMK3hVa5" target="_blank">Discord</a>
                    </div>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Kontakta oss</a></li>
                <li><a href="/ungmedlem" target="_blank">Ung Medlem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is the css for the dropdown-item class:

```css
.dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem 1.5rem;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0; }
```

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Code has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `position` attribute of the dropdown i.e., the element within which dropdown must be present should have `position: relative` and your dropdown list `position: absolute`.

Could you please add some code with your question to get more helpful answers

Edit: Checked your site
Just remove the `overflow: hidden` on `<header>` tag

```
header {
  overflow: unset; // change here
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 40px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Comment: I see you have added the code, could you please provide `dropdown-item` class css code

Comment: It has been added

Comment: is there a link to your site or is it local?

Comment: try adding position absolute to dropdown-item and position relative to dropdown-menu?

Comment: You can find the site here: https://samhalletsunga.se/

Comment: checkout the edited answer, if this answers the question do close this by checking the answer right